# Show that f a holomorphic map, is either infinite or a rational function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f :C \cup {\infty} \to C \cup {\infty}$ be a holomorphic map from the Riemann sphere to itself. Show that f
is either identically $\infty$, or is a rational function in the sense that there exist polynomials $P(z), Q(z)$ of one complex variable, with Q not identically zero, such that $f(z) = P(z) / Q(z) \forall {z \in {\bf C}} $ with $Q(z) \neq 0$.

My first question is how do I show f has finitely many poles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We denote the Riemann sphere as $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$. If $f:\widehat{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic then $f$ is constant, indeed $f$ being continuous at $\infty$, there exists a compact $K\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is bounded on $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus K$. Since $f$ is also bounded on $K$, $f$ is bounded on $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ and thus is constant. Now let $f:\widehat{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ holomorphic which is not a constant function, then $f$ has a finite number of zeroes and singularities, $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ being compact. Let $F\in\mathbb{C}(X)$ such that $F$ has the same zeroes and singularities (counted with multiplicity) than $f$, then $f/F:\widehat{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and thus is constant so that $f$ is a rational function.

Comment: Is $fF$ holomorphic because the zeroes and singularities cancel each other, and is therefore constant? Then f would be a constant/F and is therefore rational. Is this the right interpretation of your answer @Tuvasbien?

Comment: Yes absolutely (I also made a mistake, it is $f/F$ that is holomorphic, not $fF$)

Comment: Not sure the OP sees that you meant $f$ is meromorphic because of the definition of holomorphic to the Riemann sphere

Comment: If $f/F$ is constant, then f is not a rational function @Tuvasbien

Comment: @reuns if f is holomorphic to the Riemann sphere does it mean it is meromorphic - I dont understand.

Comment: $f$ is Holomorphic $U\to \Bbb{C}\cup \infty$ means that $f$ is meromorphic $U\to \Bbb{C}$, ie. either $f$ or $1/f$ is holomorphic (to $\Bbb{C}$) around each point. This is because the Riemann sphere is (by definition) covered by two charts from $|z|<2$: $z\to z$ and $z\to 1/z$.

Comment: By the way @Tuvasbien you didn't show that $f$ has the same number of zeros and poles which is necessary to find $F$. I would put in $F$ only the zeros poles on $\Bbb{C}$ then substract a polynomial to make $f/F-p$ holomorphic at $\infty$.